# Why filename with space are not getting complied in terminal in VS Code?

Tags: c

I wrote a Simple HelloWorld C program and saved it as C Program.c in VS Code

I am getting following error:

> PS E:\C> gcc C Program.c
> gcc.exe: error: C: No such file or directory
> gcc.exe: error: Program.c: No such file or directory
> gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
> compilation terminated.

Though when I changed th name to CProgram.c it was complied and gave the output

> PS E:\C> gcc CProgram.c
> PS E:\C> .\a.exe
> Hello World!

Please provide a solution to execute .c files with spaces in their name

Comment: I'd not use spaces in filenames. There are solutions for your problems, but it's usually a hassle.

Comment: Terminological confusion — you don't execute C files; you compile them into programs that can be executed.  You then execute the compiled program.

Comment: if you don't quote the string with spaces then how can the compiler know that `gcc -option my file.c` means `gcc -option "my file.c"`, `gcc "-option my file.c"` or `gcc "-option my" file.c`? All of those are valid file names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to enclose the file name in quotes (of some sort — on Unix-like systems, either single or double quotes would work):

```
gcc "C Program.c"
gcc 'C Program.c'
```

Without the quotes, you provide three separate arguments on the command line, `gcc` and `C` and `Program.c` and the files `C` and `Program.c` don't exist, hence you get the errors you show.

Given that you're on Windows, you probably need to use the double quotes.

However, your life will be easier if you give up on using spaces in source code file names.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces are used as separator of commandline arguments, so you have to surround the strings by `""` if you want to pass filenames with spaces.

```
PS E:\C> gcc "C Program.c"
```